# How to fix this TestNG Exception?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

I am getting below exception but I havent given any @Configuration tag in the below mentioned class.

org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'url' is required by @Configuration on method login but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in RunOEE.xml

Below is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="OEE_Suite" parallel = "classes">
    <test name="testCases">
        <classes>
            <class name="testCasesOEE.Login" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Below is my login method:

```
  @Parameters({"browser"} )
    @BeforeMethod()
    public void login(String browser) throws IOException {
        startApp(browser);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

1, You are calling parameter `@Parameters({"browser"}` in your test and not specifying value of parameter in your testng.xml. add `<parameter name="Visit" value="123456"/>` in your tesng.xml and run it again.

your testng.xml will look like below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="OEE_Suite" parallel = "classes">
    <test name="testCases">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="testCasesOEE.Login" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

2. In testng xml mentioned below check your  tag. it should be like packagename.classname.
3. if you are running the code from class then it is wrong approach. run your code first time by executing testng.xml.

Hope this helps